# vue-croppa: get original image and use as initial image for another Croppa component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I want to get access to the original image the user uploads via [vue-croppa](https://github.com/zhanziyang/vue-croppa). I want to display various different `vue-croppa` components (with different dimensions), but want to let the user upload his image to the first `vue-croppa` component. Then, all other `vue-croppa` components should access the chosen image from the first component, and should update/display the image within their space.

I tried to make use of the `generateDataUrl()` function, stored this via `vuex` in the state, added a `watcher` to the `vue-croppa` component in order to observe state changes and to update all `vue-croppa` components. This works fine, but only if all other croppa components have the same dimensions, and it also just works with the displayed, already cropped, image, not with the original image.

How can I access the original image? I wasn't able to find anything like that in the docs.

My code so far:

**HTML**

```
<my-img-cropper :previewwidth="200" :previewheight="200"></my-img-cropper>
<my-img-cropper :previewwidth="400" :previewheight="200"></my-img-cropper>
```

**myimgcroppa.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <croppa 
        v-model="croppa"
        :width="previewwidth" 
        :height="previewheight"
        :initial-image="initialImage"
        @loading-end="imageChanged()"
    ></croppa>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
import Croppa from 'vue-croppa';

export default {
  name: "MyImgCropper",
  props: [
    'previewwidth',
    'previewheight'
  ],
  components: {
    croppa: Croppa.component
  },
  data() {
    return {
      croppa: {},
      dataUrl: '',
      initialImage: null,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    imageChanged: function() {
      this.$store.state.img = this.croppa.generateDataUrl();
    },
  },
  watch: {
    myState: function(val){
      var image = new Image();
      image.src = this.$store.state.img;
      this.initialImage = image;
      this.croppa.refresh();
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging through the docs it was easier than I initially thought. There exists a data attribute that directly contains the original image source and I only had to change a single line.

So in the end the complete code looks like:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <croppa 
        v-model="croppa"
        :width="previewwidth" 
        :height="previewheight"
        :initial-image="initialImage"
        @loading-end="imageChanged()"
    ></croppa>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
import Croppa from 'vue-croppa';

export default {
  name: "MyImgCropper",
  props: [
    'previewwidth',
    'previewheight'
  ],
  components: {
    croppa: Croppa.component
  },
  data() {
    return {
      croppa: {},
      dataUrl: '',
      initialImage: null,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    imageChanged: function() {
      //this.$store.state.img = this.croppa.generateDataUrl();
      this.$store.state.img = this.croppa.originalImage.src; //use vuex mutations to update the state!!
    },
  },
  watch: {
    myState: function(val){
      var image = new Image();
      image.src = this.$store.state.img;
      this.initialImage = image;
      this.croppa.refresh();
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

If you'd like to use this code, please make sure do not mutate the `state` of `vuex` directly (as commented in the code above), but to use a `setter` method. I only changed the `state` directly for development purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Currently working on something similar as I found your question. Your content helped me, maybe this will help you.

I have this in my data section:

```
data: function() {
        return {
            memberPhoto: ''

        }
    },
```

I had an input:

```
<input id="photo-hidden-input" @change="photoUploaded" type="file" accept="image/*">
```

I had these methods:

```
photoUploaded: function(event) {
    var files = event.target.files;

    if (!files.length) {
       return
    }

    this.setMemberPhoto(files[0]);

},

setMemberPhoto(file) {
    this.memberPhoto = URL.createObjectURL(file);
},
```

I have this in my html:

```
<img id="photoElement" v-if="memberPhoto != ''" 
    class="photo-file" :src="memberPhoto" />
```

To access my original image, it's stored with this part: **URL.createObjectURL(file)**

Comment: Thank you very much gboone. Vue-croppa does provide a `originalImage` object.